# Extracting portions of strings from a text file

Tags: c++

So, it goes something like this.

I have this file with a list of URLs that I put into an array.

I have to write some code to extract the domain names from each of these URLs.

But the format of these URLs are not certain. They might have "http://" or "https://" or "www." in front, or just start as "google.com/..." As for the back part, I'd have to cut off right after the ".com" or ".gov", etc.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to code this.

Comment: Split in front of the first dot (if it exists) and the last dot (if it exists).

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: Usually you need to develop something like this incrementally. Start by removing pieces you know have to go, like everything from the beginning to a `//` (if you find that). Then remove everything from the first `/` (again, if you find one) to the end, and so on until you've chopped off all the pieces you don't need.

Comment: You can use split if it's simple, or you can use regex if it's more complicated

Comment: If they don't start with a scheme identifier, they are not URLs.  It's that simple.  If you want to convert something else to a URL, then that's a whole different question.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string and get root name of domain.

I will suggest you to try regular expression like this

`(/^http?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);`

`(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);`

`(/^https?\:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);`